# SW Trigger Actions calls multiple instances of PS script that creates a log file. How to ensure no logging gets missed

Tags: powershell, logging

So I have had the fun task of integrating `Solarwinds` and `Remedy ARS 7.x` and all is well except for logging.  When `Solarwinds` generates an alert, a trigger calls a `PowerShell` script.  Depending on how busy the environment, a single trigger can fire or multiple triggers can fire.  Regardless the number, each call to the script writes to a single log file.

What I am finding is that if I have 5 or fewer simultaneous calls of the script, logging is fine.  If 20 or so get called simultaneously, I am missing entries in my log file.   I've looked at various examples but not seem to use the same logging method as I do,

```
Start-Transact/Stop-Transact.
```

In the main function, logging is initiated like the following:

```
$ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
Stop-Transcript | out-null
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
Start-Transcript -path $LogFile -append
```

And each exit point, logging is stopped like the following:

```
Stop-Transcript
Exit
```

It takes at max 60 seconds to complete a run.  Do I just merely add some code at the beginning of the script that checks to see if the file is closed or not?  And if it is, wait 10 seconds, 30 seconds, or 60 seconds?

Time sensitive.  Appreciate any direction provided.

R. Gaines

Comment: May be the answer on your problem is a [mutex](https://learn-powershell.net/2014/09/30/using-mutexes-to-write-data-to-the-same-logfile-across-processes-with-powershell/)?

Comment: Andrei Odegov, thanks for your reply.  I found this link and it sounds just like what I am needing to do.  Hwevr, not sure how to incorporate into my existing code.  https://learn-powershell.net/2014/09/30/using-mutexes-to-write-data-to-the-same-logfile-across-processes-with-powershell/